# How can I post text with Facebook feed dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, lua, coronasdk

I write application in Lua with Corona SDK. I want to post some unique text with Facebook feed dialog. My code is:

```
facebook.showDialog( "feed", {message = "This is my unique text"  }  )
```

I tried also:

```
local text_arr = {}
text_arr.text = "This is my unique text"
facebook.showDialog( "feed", {properties = text_arr }  )
```

Both of them don't work. I don't see the "This is my unique" string on my wall after dialog publish action.
So , how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Did you logged in to facebook using facebook.login( ) first?

Comment: Yes, I logged before with facebook.login()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the user logs in to facebook, which you need to do with:

```
facebook.login( appId, listener )
```

You can now send requests to the facebook graph API using request function:

```
facebook.request( "me/feed", "POST", {message = "Hello Facebook"} )
```

You can check the documentation page here http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/request.html

If you really want to use the dialog, which I have never tried, I suppose you have to define some more parameters:

From what I can understand from http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/facebook/showDialog.html and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/ it should turn out to be something like this:

```
facebook.showDialog( "feed", {
    redirect_uri = "YOUR_URL",
    link = "YOUR_LINK",
    picture = "YOUR_PICTURE_URL",
    name = "DIALOG_NAME",
    caption = "DIALOG_CAPTION",
    description = "DIALOG_DESCRIPTION" 
})
```

Some properties are probably optional, so mess around with it a bit...